# How to do a composite search in bing search API?

Tags: php, json, azure

I'm trying to do a composite search in bing search API using php. From this [documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248077) i got this.

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=%27web%2bnews%27&Query=%27XBox%27&$top=1 This gives some result which i don't know to parse and show the result. I tried  `simplexml_load_file()` to parse but no use.
```

If i mention json format request like below i get a bad request sent error( failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request) and `file_get_contents()` error

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=%27web%2bnews%27&?$format=json&Query=%27XBox%27&$top=1
```

How to get the result with json?

Answer (score 0):

Correct query for you is: (I removed "?" before $format=json)

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=%27web%2bnews%27&$format=json&Query=%27XBox%27&$top=1
```